# Path of Node Red node on PI

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian, node-red

I try to install the sensorTag package with npm. 
[GitHub Link](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes/tree/master/hardware/sensorTag)

In the readme I have to set executable by non-root user, with the following command:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+eip $(eval readlink -f `which node`)
```

I'm new with PI, Node Red and Raspbian. Can someone say what 'which node' mean? Where can I find the path?

Is the path from `process.execPath` the correct path?

Comment: Hi Sean - I've already answered this question on the github issue you raised. You run that command exactly as written - `which node` is not meant to be a placeholder for you to insert something different.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which is a linux command to find where 'node' is installed
setcap set's same file permissions to cap_net.. as found for the link where node is installed...

all abit complicate, basically it allows users to access cap_net as mentioned on the github side